# Missing python files with pip install from Nexus

Tags: python-3.x, pip, nexus

I have successfully upload my python package to Nexus. When I look in the package folder, there are two files :

- *.whl
- *tar.gz

When I run the pip install command :

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --index-url https://nexus.my_host.com/repository/pypi-public/simple my_lib==0.0.0
```

It returns a success.

When I look into the site-packages I only see the dist-info and the python files are missing.

Here my setup.py :

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(HERE, "README.md")) as f:
    README = f.read()
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()
setup(
    name='my_lib',
    version='0.0.0',
    description='My Lib',
    install_requires=requirements,
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=find_packages(
        exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
    license='MIT',
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    ])
```

My tree looks like this :

```
/main_dir
  sources/
    __init__.py
    my_file.py
  setup.py
```

When I look in the tar.gz file there is the sources/ folder with my_file.py.

Thanks for replies guys and have a nice day !

Comment: Are you by chance missing the `__init__.py` files in the package directories?

Comment: Yes I have __init__.py I have updated my post with more details :)

Comment: As presented in the question, the _top-level_ module seems to be `sources` (are you sure that's what you want?), so you would need to do `import sources`, and would need to look for a `sources` directory in `site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc ! Well I need the content of `sources`. I would like to have something like `from my_lib import my_file`. How can I do it ?

Comment: Rename the `sources` directory to whatever you want it to be. Make sure it's not a name that is already taken, so that it doesn't cause conflicts with other projects (for example on _PyPI_).